# Reading the List of Open Networks in Cytoscape

Tags: java, cytoscape

I am trying to get a `CyNetwork[]` containing all of the networks open in the Cytoscape network tab. My understanding is that I need a `CyNetworkReader` to call `CyNetworkReader.getNetworks()` and to get a `CyNetworkReader` I need a `CyNetworkReaderManager`. However, I don't know how to get a `CyNetworkReaderManager`, nor do I know the proper `InputStream` or input name to use `CyNetworkReaderManager.getReader()`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.  Actually, you would need a CyNetworkReader to read in a new network from disk.  If you want to get the list of currently loaded networks, you would need to use the CyNetworkManager.getNetworkSet() method.  To get a handle on the CyNetworkManager, you just need to get it from OSGi, so in your CyActivator, you would do something like:

```
CyNetworkManager cyNetworkManager = getService(CyNetworkManager.class);
```

That's it.

Comment: I had to add the bundle context as an argument to `getService()` then it worked, thank you.